# what is the limit of $\lim_{n\to\infty} [n^n/e^nn!]$

Tags: calculus

How do I find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^n}{e^nn!}$ ? ...I was trying to look at this as : $n^n$ grows faster than $e^n$ and $n!$ but here is a multiplication....

Comment: Have you seen [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation)?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Method (I)

Let $A(n)=\frac{n^n}{e^nn!}$, and $B(n)=\log A(n)=n\log n -n -\sum_{i=1}^n \log n$  then

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^n}{e^nn!}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\exp(\log A(n))=\lim_{n \to \infty}\exp(B(n))=\exp(\lim_{n \to \infty}B(n))$$

$\lim_{n \to \infty}B(n)=\lim_{n \to \infty}n\log n -n -\sum_{i=1}^n \log n=+\infty$ (This can be derived from Sterling's approximation)

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^n}{e^nn!}=+\infty$$

Method (II)

Relax $n$, and use l'Hopital.

Comment: This doesn't look right, since [Stirling's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) says $$\frac{n^n}{e^n\,n!}\sim\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$$ which vanishes as $n\to\infty$.